# The term 'oh-my-posh' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, wsl-2, oh-my-posh

I have configured oh-my-posh to be working on powershell and all is working as expected if I run powershell from windows terminal (which is what the document say clearly)

However I tend to run powershell from my WSL terminal as I have alias like this
**psl='/mnt/c/Program\ Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe'**

but now when I run that alias I got the following error

```
oh-my-posh: C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:19
Line |
  19 |  oh-my-posh init pwsh --config 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Powe …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'oh-my-posh' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the
     | name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

I tried to change the path but it seems the terminal is not recognize the oh-my-posh

Comment: Is oh-my-posh visible/available to your WSL user?

Comment: How do I check that? I'm basically moving from wsl to PowerShell via the alias

Comment: check $env:PATH

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, validate the location of the executable using `Get-Command oh-my-posh` and add that to the `PATH` when starting PowerShell, preferably by adding that to your `$PROFILE`.

```
$env:Path += ";/mnt/c/Program\ Files/exact/location/oh-my-posh.exe"
```

That said, it's discouraged to use the Windows version of oh-my-posh on WSL as that will be slower than a native linux build. Same goes for the Windows version of PowerShell.